# Prevent Telerik Radbutton postback during form data validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik, postback

I am trying to prevent postback of the page using JQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#<%= btnAddAircraft.ClientID %>').click(function() {
            var Passengers = $('#<%= txtPassengers.ClientID %>').val();
            if (parseInt(Passengers) == 0) 
            {
                $('#<%= txtPassengers.ClientID %>').focus();
                alert("Number of passengers should not be Zero.");
                return false;                
            }

            });
    });
```

```
<telerik:radbutton id="btnAddAircraft" onclick="btnAddAircraft_Click" validationgroup="P1" text="Add Aircraft" runat="server"> </telerik:radbutton>
```

The Validation process occurs but cannot retain the control to prevent postback.

Note: This issue I have handled using `OnClientClick` event of `RadButton`. But I want to work it out in my `document.ready` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to attach to the OnClientClicking client-side event, which can be cancelled. Telerik uses for events Clicking/Clicked event names.  See the events for more information: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/button/examples/clientsideevents/defaultcs.aspx

To cancel, you should be able to set `e.set_cancel(true);`

Because it's ASP.NET AJAX, you can't attach to AJAX components in document.ready; the AJAX isn't initialized in time for that to work.